# Deactivate Mobile Content from Website in WebView

Tags: android

Hy my code:

```
            WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.preisjaeger.at");
        setContentView(webView);
```

The site the i downloaded appers on the Webview, but only the content for mobile devices.

So my Question: How to deactivate the mobile content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mobile content is being loaded because that site is detecting that you are on a mobile device.  I would suggest trying to spoof the browser [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string in a way that would make that site think you are not on a mobile device.

Use the method `webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString()`

Comment: asnd what string should i add?

Comment: You might try spoofing Chrome, or just make up your own user agent string.